# MVC3 Enable disable button razor

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

How can I enable or disable button after check box checked and unchecked ? If user agree the terms and condition and then he checked check box after that button must be enable to user.

I use following code

**example.chtml**

```
<input id="termsandcondition" type="checkbox" value="false" onclick="if(this.value==true)this.btnsubmit.Enabled=true;else this.btnsubmit.Enabled=false;"/>

<input id="btnsubmit" type="submit" value="Register" class="cssLoginButton" disabled="disabled" />
```

But I am not able to enable or disable button. Is there any change in my code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
document.getElementById('btnsubmit').disabled = !this.checked;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using jquery

```
$("#checkBoxID").click(function() {
 $("#buttonID").attr("disabled", !this.checked);
});
```

Your answer accept ratio is not good, please look towards it